# My printer is not printing black text

Tags: printer

My printer is not printing black ink. I have never used any other cartridges but the Epson ones for my machine. I keep cleaning and priming and wasting new cartridges.Epson Workforce WF-2630

Comment: Where did you buy your cartridges from?

Comment: How old is your printer?  Does it sit unused for extended periods?  What happens when you print a nozzle test pattern?  How old is the ink?

Answer (score 1):

Epson printers have a print head separate from the ink cartridge. It is easily possible that your print head has either clogged on the black ink portion or that the head itself has failed.

I have replaced a print head for a friend which solved the problem, but failed again less than a year later.

Consider that you have little to lose if the head is bad by performing an out-of-printer cleaning. Remove the ink cartridges, remove the head assembly and place the bottom portion in an alcohol bath. You can also pour some alcohol into the top bay for the black cartridge. The best thing that can happen is that the alcohol will dissolve the clog. The worst thing is that the print head will cease to operate on all colors.

This is an option only if you are planning to purchase a replacement if this method fails. Use as high concentration alcohol that you can find for best results. Isopropyl alcohol, also known as rubbing alcohol. I believe that denatured alcohol will also work.

It will be necessary to re-prime the head after returning it to the printer, as the alcohol will have cleaned away all pre-primed ink.